# Vue 3.0 router components transition does not work with mode="out-in"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router4

I building an application with vue 3.0 and vue-router 4.0.

I have this very simple code in my `App.vue` component (first rendered component) :

```js
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
        <component :is="Component"></component>
    </transition>
</router-view>
```

First page is renderer - no problem. But as soon as I navigate to another page, page become blank. If I remove the `mode="out-in"` it works (but transition is ugly).

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Do you get any error in ur console?

Comment: Unfortunately none...

Comment: It could be a CSS problem unless the router is configured incorrectly.  There's not enough code in the post to tell

Comment: Why do you place the transition inside router-view instead of wrapping router-view inside it ?!?

Comment: Please post more info

Comment: @IVOGELOV : This is how it must be done with vue 3 (vue-router 4) see https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found were the mistake was, and how stupid it was...

In my template, I put a comment before the first tag:

```html
<template>

    <!-- login layout --> <=== NOT A GOOD IDEA...
    <div class="lsn-login">
        ...
    </div>

</template>
```

Thank you for all your comment.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Mark it as answer! This is really weird, comments must not affect rendering.

Comment: Faced this problem today. Spent solid 2 hours reading through official documents and migrations [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#router-view-keep-alive-and-transition) and [there](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0034-router-view-keep-alive-transitions.md#summary). Just to finally comes out that my comment is the problem. This is wierd

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would have search for hours, couldn't imagine this problem

Comment: To be clear, the answer is a combination of this and Fabio Almeida's below: the real answer is that you can only have 1 root node when using transitions (with the comment counting as a node)

Answer (score 4):

Each template can only have one tag (element). The following example would break the transitions

```
<template>
  <div class="about"></div>
  <img class="back-img" src="/artwork/58.webp"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this problem is that transition only supports a single element.
[The official document hints](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component):

```
<Transition> only supports a single element or component as its slot content. 
If the content is a component, the component must also have only one single root element.
```

You can see a demo in this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-gwfbmb?file=src%2FApp.vue

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to still be an issue as February 2024 (albeit with a couple of possible fixes in Vue's pull requests), I think it's worth clarifying that `<transition>` seems to treat top/root-level comments as if they are actual HTML nodes.

As others have noted, `<transition>` only supports a single element or component. As a result, if you are using it as follows:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <SomeComponent />
</transition>
```

And `<SomeComponent />` has a template as follows:

```
<template>
  <!-- Some comment -->
  <div> My Content </div>
</template>
```

That single comment will cause any transitions you apply to fail. It will even fail if you move the comment under the div in the template of `<SomeComponent />`

The fix is simple enough:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Some comment -->
    My Content 
  </div>
</template>
```

Of course, these cases are fairly easy to notice even if the error isn't obvious.

BUT it is much less obvious when dealing with Vue-Router, in particular when you use the following common pattern:

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
  <Transition :name="route.meta.transition" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </Transition>
</router-view>
```

Now every possible Route's component that has a top/root-level comment can cause the issue to arise.

Similarly, the issue can appear if you're using a container/wrapper component without any comments.

Let's say we had `<ContainerComponent />` that provides special styling to `<SomeComponent />` in the root of the template, it may be easy to miss that the issue is due to the child `<SomeComponent />`

Hopefully this reaches and helps anyone who may be having this issue!